# 'onDraw()' called twice when 'invalidate' is called for the first time

Tags: android, android-custom-view, custom-view

I can't understand why the first time I call `this.invalidate` in a custom view, the method `onDraw()` is called twice (performing double operations on the same variables). After that, each time the user presses a button, `onDraw()` is called once, as it should be. Here is the code:

**MyActivity**

```
MyView mCustomView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_interval_identification);

    mCustomView = (MyView) findViewById(R.id.my_view);
    Button mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.id_btn);

    mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            newDrawing();
        }
    });

    newDrawing();

}

private void newDrawing() {

    int a;
    int b;

    //some operations on 'a' and 'b'

    mCustomView.newDrawing(a, b);

}
```

**MyView**

```
int x;
int y;

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    Drawable object = ContextCompat.getDrawable(getContext(), R.drawable.object);

    //some operations

    object.draw(canvas); //based on 'x' and 'y'
}

public void newDrawing(int a, int b) {
    x = a;
    y = b;
    this.invalidate();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to comment `newDrawing();` (`newDrawing(); --> //newDrawing();`) in your `onCreate` method in `MyActivity`. It seems first time `onDraw` is called by the system automatically.

Comment: It doesn't work. The object is not drawn correctly because 'a' and 'b' have not been set.

Comment: You could check if parameters `a` and `b` have been set already in `onDraw` method (using some `boolean`, for example), so, it should draw the object only when `a`, `b` are known.

Comment: But in this way the object will not be drawn until the user presses the button and `newDrawing()` is called.